# How to find the date format of a string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Is there a way (an elegant way that is) to extract a date format from a string containing a date so that it may be converted into an NSDate via NSDateFormatter?

i.e

```
string = @"2011-1-10";
format = [extractor extractFormat:string];// format would = yyyy-dd-mm
[formatter setDateFormatter:format];
NSDate * date = [formatter dateFromString:string];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is the only information you have then it is impossible. For example, "10-10-10".

Comment: +1 that's clearly 10 minutes and 10 seconds after the start of year 10.

Comment: You *could* try your luck with Data Detectors. The example year Eric gives *is* a four-digit year. As I understand it, data detectors go by locale, so "DD-MM" versus "MM-DD" could be inferred. I think data detectors would guess more dates correctly than you're giving credit for. :-) The important message still applies, though - it's inexact and would need human verification.

Comment: Joshua, I thought of something like that, but I decided to bite the bullet and leave it to the user to pick what date format their report is going to use. Thanks anyways.